# Как добавить \n после 34 символа? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, перенос, перенос-слов

У меня есть строка с пробелами: "***Противоположная точка зрения подразумевает, что многие известные личности, инициированные исключительно синтетически, своевременно верифицированы.***"

И мне нужно, чтобы после 34 символа в этом предложении подставился \n ,следовательно после подставки остальная часть предложения перенесётся.

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5254455/7485582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать новую строку со вставленным необходимым символом:

```
s = "Противоположная точка зрения подразумевает, что многие известные личности, инициированные исключительно синтетически, своевременно верифицированы."
s = s[:34] + '\n' + s[34:]
```